# Selecting column "BY" with Google Query Language

Tags: google-sheets, gql

I am trying to select column "BY" (the one after column BX and before column BZ) from a query in Google Spreadsheet, but it seems that column name or identifier is recognized as a special word of the query language (as order "by"), so there is no way I can get the query working.

I have tried to use single quotation mark ('BY') inside the query, and other variations, but none of them worked.

Is there any way I can select values on column "BY" inside a QUERY instance?

Example of Formula not working:

```
=if($B18=0, "select an item", QUERY($A14:$DO16, "SELECT A WHERE BY="&MAX(BY14:BY16)))
```

Error message:

```
Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROREncountered "BY" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ... "not" ... "date" ... "timeofday" ... "datetime" ... "timestamp" ... "min" ... "max" ... "avg" ... "count" ... "sum" ... "no_values" ... "no_format" ... "is" ... "null" ... "year" ... "month" ... "day" ... "hour" ... "minute" ... "second" ... "millisecond" ... "with" ... "contains" ... "starts" ... "ends" ... "matches" ... "like" ... "now" ... "dateDiff" ... "quarter" ... "lower" ... "upper" ... "dayOfWeek" ... "toDate" ... <ID> ... <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <DECIMAL_LITERAL> ..
```

Example of same formula working fine when using other columns:

```
=if($B18=0, "Select an item", QUERY($A14:$DO16, "SELECT A WHERE BX="&MAX(BX14:BX16)))
```

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this place backticks (the key to the left of the 1 key) around the BY column expression:

```
=if($B18=0, "select an item", QUERY($A14:$DO16, "SELECT A WHERE `BY`="&MAX(BY14:BY16)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the use of "backquotes" (``) was the only one that resolved my problem.